# Cannot compile EZAudio in Xcode 6 beta 5

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I'm attempting to use [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) in my Swift application. I've added the Objective C bridging header, however I still receive the following error:

```
Function definition is not allowed here (line 34) in EZPlot.h
```

With this line:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger,EZPlotType){
```

I realise it's early days with this version of Xcode, but has anyone managed to get the thing to compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a prefix header to your project will resolve the problem. Don't forget to change your build settings after that.

see the edit on this post => https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio/issues/63#issuecomment-47230912